# Hilghligth columns and rows in different tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm following this [Table Row and Column Highlighting](https://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/) method with the *Delegate* option to highlight rows and columns in a table. Works fine in a first table, but I'm not able to separate the effect when using two different tables at the same page: at the second table, the rows are highlighted but the columns are not isolated just a the current table but highlight the first one.

I already tried different alternatives modifying the script with no luck.

See the code snippet:

```js
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
      $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
      $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```

```css
table.blueTable {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 4px 4px;
}
table.blueTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}

table.blueTable thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #353535;
  width: 80px;
}


.slim { width: 88px; }
.hover { background-color: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>First Table</h1>
<table class="blueTable">
<colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head2</th>
<th>head3</th>
<th>head4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell1_1</td><td>cell2_1</td><td>cell3_1</td><td>cell4_1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_2</td><td>cell2_2</td><td>cell3_2</td><td>cell4_2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_3</td><td>cell2_3</td><td>cell3_3</td><td>cell4_3</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_4</td><td>cell2_4</td><td>cell3_4</td><td>cell4_4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<h1>Second Table</h1>
<table class="blueTable">
<colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
    <colgroup class="slim"></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head2</th>
<th>head3</th>
<th>head4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell1_1</td><td>cell2_1</td><td>cell3_1</td><td>cell4_1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_2</td><td>cell2_2</td><td>cell3_2</td><td>cell4_2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_3</td><td>cell2_3</td><td>cell3_3</td><td>cell4_3</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_4</td><td>cell2_4</td><td>cell3_4</td><td>cell4_4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("colgroup") doesn't refer to the colgroup inside the table that was clicked, just the first colgroup on the page. Try replacing

```
$("colgroup").eq(...)
```

with

```
$(this).closest("table").find("colgroup").eq(...)
```